# Select only the entries that have the same foreign_id twice

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have a mysql InnoDB table with the following structure:

```
id
artist_id
```

There are many entries in there, most artist_ids are in there like 15 times. But some are in there only twice. I need to get those.

I have come up with the following, to no avail:

```
SELECT artist_id FROM matches HAVING COUNT(artist_id)=2
```

It returns 0 rows, although there are artist_ids that only appear in the table twice. How can I get them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello,
I would use this:
`SELECT artist_id,count(*) FROM matches 
 GROUP BY artist_id
 HAVING COUNT(*)=2`
because `HAVING` is a filter of the results.

With `=2` you will find the ones that exist exactly twice.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Well, that doesn't help. It only shows me the first artist_id and the count of all rows. I need the artist_ids that appear only twice in the table.

Comment: It has to be `=2`, not `>1`, but apart from that it's perfectly fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
select artist_id, count(id) as num from matches group by artist_id having num = 2;
```